# Should the partitions related to a particular OS be continuous?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning

My Disk Management Window:

[image]

I want to shrink my C drive and create a partition. In that partition Ubuntu will be installed.

But I doubt one thing, Will my Recovery Partition work if i create that ubuntu partition in between the C Drive and Recovery Partition

my SSD will be partitioned like this

| EFI sys partition(windows) | C drive(windows) | partition for Ubuntu | Recovery partition(windows) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 260mb | 200gb | 275gb | 1000mb |

I don't want to lose my recovery partition

My computer is a new one.

should I delete this recovery partition then create that ubuntu partition and then create my system image after that C Drive partition? If I do so then the partition order will be like as follows:

| EFI sys partition(windows) | C drive(windows) | [new]Recovery partition(windows) | partition for Ubuntu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Comment: Won't it be much simpler to install Ubuntu after C?

Comment: The location of the recovery partition shouldn't matter. Depending on your computer it may not even be necessary as you can always download a clean Windows 10 image direct from Microsoft or potentially even get a recovery image from your manufacturer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should create a full disk image before working with partitions so that you can restore your computer if a disaster happens. You should also make sure that your regular automated backups are working and restorable. (If you don't have automated backups, you should - unless there's no valuable data whatsoever on this computer.)

Order of partitions doesn't matter. You can go ahead and simply shrink C:.

Don't delete the recovery partition. It's the contents of this partition that matters. A new, empty recovery partition isn't of much use.